# Getting input value with freemarker

Tags: html, spring, freemarker

I simply forgot how to work with freemarker. I tried to create input, after submission which value of it gonna be displayed on the other page. It looks awful but here is my code :

```
@GetMapping("/form1")
public String getForm(){
    return "form1";
}
@GetMapping("/name11/{Name}")
public String formPos(@PathVariable("Name") String name, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "name11";
}
```

html named form1

```
<form action="/name11" method="post">
<input name="Name" >
<button>put</button>
</form>
```

html named name11

```
<body>
<h1>${name}</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Use `${(name)}` instead of `${name}`. Which you could have gotten with one glance at the getting-started on the freemarker site.

Comment: Also it isn't a `@PathVariable` you are getting it is just an `@RequestParam` you are getting.

Comment: @M.Deinum What's with `${(name)}` instead of `${name}`? They mean the same in FreeMarker.

Comment: I had issues with the plain version in my templates. Nonetheless your controller is wrong as you aren't sending a path variable but a request parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@GetMapping("/form1")
public String getForm() {
    return "form1";
}

@PostMapping("/name11")
public String formPos(@RequestParam("Name") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "name11";
}
```

form1 in static directory as form1.html

name11 in template directory as name11.ftlh